# Python/wxPython Black Box Glitch

Tags: python, wxpython, visual-glitch

Perhaps this is best asked on the wxPython mailing list, but I thought I'd ask here first to see if it is a known issue (I couldn't find anything about it via google).

If my computer has been on for awhile (Windows), then my wxPython applications will often be displayed weird, with black boxes over many widgets and my desktop background visible around the borders (see image).  This MIGHT only happen on frames with a notebook, but I can't confirm this right now.  The computer has 3GB of RAM and over 1GB free, but I still get this glitching.  If I restart, it will display fine for awhile before appearing messed up again.

The image below is of wxGlade.  I used it to show that it doesn't only happen in the programs I write, but in (all?) wxPython programs.  So I don't believe this has anything to do with my coding.

Specs:

- Python 2.5.2 (32bit install)
- wxPython 2.8.11.0 (32bit install)
- 64bit Windows XP
- 3GB RAM
- Nvidia Quadro FX 3500

This is a work computer, and unfortunately I don't have the ability to install any version of the software I wish.  I don't notice this glitch on my linux box at home.  Is there some work-around, or anything I can do to see what might cause this issue?  Thanks!

[image: wxPython_Issue]

Comment: I have never seen that happen on any of the Windows (XP or 7) machines I've installed my applications on. That's a weird one.

Comment: There are lot of bugs in the windows implementation of wxpython (and there is perhaps no solution to it), so for now, just forget it and hope that it will be soon fixed in the later versions.

Comment: are you sure your computer is not overheating? if it only happens after x hours, that may be the case - check inside and remove all dust.

Comment: Everything else runs fine, only wxPython gives me these issues.  No other programs/applications.  And if I restart the computer, it works again immediately.  I'd think that this would suggest that it isn't an overheating problem (though I'm sure it could use a nice cleaning anyway).  I was thinking it is either some ram issue (memory getting corrupted or something), or some incompatibility between my versions of python and wx.  Thanks for the comments everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a new computer and the specs are slightly different:

- Python 2.5.2 (32bit install)
- wxPython 2.9.1.1 (32bit install)
- 64bit Windows XP
- 3.5GB RAM
- Nvidia Quadro 4000

I believe the "black box" issues was a problem with the wxPython implementation on Windows.  I don't get the black box errors anymore (with 2.9.1.1).  I installed the same version I had before, and the black boxes appeared again.  Now with 2.9.1.1, I don't seem to have the black boxes, BUT now I have some other issues!  I can't use newer wxPython versions because I cannot install a newer version of Python...